# Computing the nth-derivative $\frac{d^{n}}{d\lambda^{n}}e^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}t}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

According to wolfram-alpha, $\frac{d^{n}}{d\lambda^{n}}e^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}t}=  \frac{(-i)^{n} (-t)^{\frac{n}{2}} }{2^{\frac{n}{2}} }e^{x \lambda-\frac{t \lambda^2}{2}} H_n(\frac{(x-t \lambda)}{\sqrt{2t}}) $

,where $H_{n}(y)=(-1)^{n}e^{y^{2}}\frac{d^{n}}{dy^{n}}e^{-y^{2}}$.

So I am wondering what will $H_n(\frac{(x-t \lambda)}{\sqrt{2t}})$ equal to; what will $\frac{d^{n}}{dy^{n}}$ be?

Also, how did wolfram-alpha compute the above derivative?

---

Also, is there a different way to write $\frac{d^{n}}{d\lambda^{n}}e^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}t}$?

1)Using Taylor expansion $\frac{d^{n}}{d\lambda^{n}}e^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}t}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{d^{n}}{d\lambda^{n}}\frac{(\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}t)^{k}}{k!}$

Can we compute, $\frac{d^{n}}{d\lambda^{n}}(\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^{2}}{2}t)^{k}$? Wolfram-alpha doesn't answer it for some reason.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using 
\begin{align}
D^{n}[ f(x) \, g(x) ] = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, f^{k}(x) \, g^{n-k}(x)
\end{align}
then it is seen that 
\begin{align}
D^{n} [ e^{a x} \, e^{- b x^{2}/2} ] &= e^{ax} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, D^{k}(e^{-bx^{2}/2}) \, a^{n-k} \\
&= e^{ax- bx^{2}/2} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{k} \binom{n}{k} \, \left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^{k/2} \, a^{n-k} \, H_{n}\left( \sqrt{\frac{b}{2}} x \right).  \\
\end{align}

Now using the formula
\begin{align}
H_{n}(x+y) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \, H_{k}(x) \, (2y)^{n-k}
\end{align}
then it is seen that
\begin{align}
H_{n}\left( \sqrt{\frac{b}{2}} \, x - \frac{a}{\sqrt{2b}} \right) = (-1)^{n} \left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^{n/2} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \,  \left(- \frac{2a}{\sqrt{2b}}\right)^{n-k} \, H_{n}\left( \sqrt{\frac{b}{2}} x \right).
\end{align}

Now
\begin{align}
D^{n} [ e^{a x} \, e^{- b x^{2}/2} ] &= (-1)^{n} \left(\frac{2}{b}\right)^{n/2}
e^{ax- bx^{2}/2} \, H_{n}\left( \sqrt{\frac{b}{2}} \, x - \frac{a}{\sqrt{2b}} \right) 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the generalization of the chain rule for higher-order derivatives, the [Faà di Bruno formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno's_formula). I'll write its combinatorial form here, but the Wikipedia article has other forms of it:
 $$
 \frac{d^n}{d\lambda^n} f(g(\lambda))=(f\circ g)^{(n)}(\lambda)=\sum_{\pi\in\Pi} f^{(\left|\pi\right|)}(g(\lambda))\cdot\prod_{B\in\pi}g^{(\left|B\right|)}(\lambda)
$$
where the sum runs over all set partitions of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and the product runs over the blocks of a given partition. Let's work out the second derivative of your function with this formula.

The partitions of the set $\{1,2\}$ are simply $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2\}\}$. $f$ is the exponential function and $g(\lambda)= \lambda x-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}t$. Moreover, since your $f$ is the exponential function, the $f^{(|\pi|)}(g(x))$ factors out of the summation to given an overall factor $e^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}t}$. We have
 $$
 \begin{align}
 \frac{d^2}{d\lambda^2} &= \left[\frac{d^2}{d\lambda^2}g(\lambda)+\left(\frac{dg(\lambda)}{d\lambda}\right)^2\right]e^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}t}\\
       &=\left[-t+(x-\lambda t)^2\right]e^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}t}
 \end{align}
 $$
which is indeed what you obtain by evaluating this explicitly.

You can simplify the higher derivatives by noting that since your $g(\lambda)$ is a quadratic terms, partitions with blocks of cardinality $>2$ will vanish.

You can compute $\frac{d^n}{d\lambda^n}\left(\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\right)^k$ in the same manner, with $f=y^k$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{equation}
u=u(\lambda)=\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^2}2t.
\end{equation}
Then, by the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the partial Bell polynomials,
\begin{align}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}\lambda^n}\operatorname{e}^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^2}2t}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(\operatorname{e}^{u})^{(k)} B_{n,k}\bigl(u'(\lambda), u''(\lambda), u'''(\lambda),\dotsc, u^{(n-k+1)}(\lambda)\bigr)\\
&=\operatorname{e}^{u}\sum_{k=0}^n B_{n,k}(x-\lambda t, -t, 0,\dotsc, 0)\\
&=\operatorname{e}^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^2}2t}\sum_{k=0}^n (-t)^k B_{n,k}\biggl(\lambda-\frac{x}{t}, 1, 0,\dotsc, 0\biggr)\\
&=\operatorname{e}^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^2}2t}\sum_{k=0}^n (-t)^k \frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}\biggl(\lambda-\frac{x}{t}\biggr)^{2k-n}\\
&=\frac{n!}{2^n}\operatorname{e}^{\lambda x-\frac{\lambda^2}2t} t^{n} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{2^k}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k} \frac{(t\lambda-x)^{2k-n}}{t^k},
\end{align}
where we used the formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-x-1-0-eq}
B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)
=\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}.
\end{equation}
For details of the above concepts, notions, and notations, please refer to related texts in the following papers.

1. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterranean Journal of Mathematics **14** (2017), no. 3, Article 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
2. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *Some properties of the Hermite polynomials*, Georgian Mathematical Journal **28** (2021), no. 6, 925--935; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/gmj-2020-2088.
3. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.